# JS filter() function - Is there a way to stop the filter reaching 0 results?

Tags: javascript, filter, velo

I have the following code, where it loops through an array, looking for a term within the keywords attributed to each object.

The code is from this tutorial by Wix (step 7) https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-tutorial-adding-a-gift-quiz-to-a-wix-stores-site

I need some logic that prevents the end returning 0 results/an empty array, but can't get my head around the loops. Ideally, it'd be the previous loop's results, when it still found results.

```js
// Filter out products that don't match the specified answer.
function filterProductsPerAnswer(quizProducts, answer) {
    // Use the JavaScript filter() function to filter out products that don't match the specified answer.
    const filteredProducts = quizProducts.filter(quizProduct => {
        return quizProduct.keywords.includes(answer)
    });
    // Return the filtered product list.
    return filteredProducts;

}
```

This is driving me mad so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `filter()` will never return undefined.  At worst, it will be an empty array

Comment: Why do you think the result will ever be undefined or 0?

Comment: In the event that the filter filters out all elements, what value do you want it to be?

Comment: @taplar you're right, sorry, it's not undefined, it's just returning a blank array. I'd rather it show the results from the previous filter loop, where it has not returned a blank array.

Comment: In that case I would suggest that this method should not change.  Instead, the method that calls this method should have conditional logic to check if the result is an empty array, and if it is, potentially ignore it and leave it as the previous filter results.

Comment: @iota my mistake, it's just blank

Comment: @taplar, that seems to have worked! so simple... wow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like pointed out in the comments by @Taplar, a solution could be another function on top of yours:

```js
    function filteredProductsOrAllProductsIfNoMatch(quizProducts answer) {
        const filteredProducts = filterProductsPerAnswer(quizProducts, answer);
        if (filteredProducts.length === 0) {
            return quizProducts;
        }
        return filteredProducts;
    }
    
    // Your original code:
    // Filter out products that don't match the specified answer.
    function filterProductsPerAnswer(quizProducts, answer) {
        // Use the JavaScript filter() function to filter out products that don't match the specified answer.
        const filteredProducts = quizProducts.filter(quizProduct => {
            return quizProduct.keywords.includes(answer)
        });
        // Return the filtered product list.
        return filteredProducts;
    }
```